# MongoDB Find | Exception - is not supported

Tags: c#, mongodb, find

I have a MongoDB database, and in it I store dates in Unix format.

But when I try to make a Find and implement a filter in it, it gives me an error.

```
FromUnixTimeSeconds({ViewsToday.Date}).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") is not supported.
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.GetFieldExpression(Expression expression)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.TranslateComparison(Expression variableExpression, ExpressionType operatorType, ConstantExpression constantExpression)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.Translate(Expression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.TranslateAndAlso(BinaryExpression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.Translate(Expression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.Translate(Expression node, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.CreateFindOperation[TProjection](FilterDefinition`1 filter, FindOptions`2 options)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.FindAsync[TProjection](IClientSessionHandle session, FilterDefinition`1 filter, FindOptions`2 options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.UsingImplicitSessionAsync[TResult](Func`2 funcAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.IAsyncCursorSourceExtensions.ToListAsync[TDocument](IAsyncCursorSource`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

My code is:

```
    var results = await Settings.DataBase.GetCollection<Video>("Videos")
        .Find(x => x.ViewsToday != null && DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(x.ViewsToday.Date).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") == DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
            .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Will WHERE work?

Comment: I did not understand the question a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `Find` has a list of "supported expressions" which can be used (through a *lambda*) as parameter - with the meaning of a filter.
Suported expression are listed (e.g.) [here](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/reference/driver/expressions/) in the official documentation of .Net driver.

In C# code you can use any C# valid expression, but when you use an expression not supported by the driver you obtain the error you're showed.

IMHO you can rewrite your query converting `DateTime.UtcNow` into unix timestamp and usig the converted value as `eq` filter (of type `long`) for `x.ViewsToday.Date`.

You can try something like this:

```
var now = DateTime.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
var results = await Settings.DataBase.GetCollection<Video>("Videos")
        .Find(x => x.ViewsToday != null && x.ViewsToday.Date == now)
            .ToListAsync();
```

EDITED

As reported in the comment, the problem is to apply an **only date** filter on an Unix timestamp containg time information, too.
Since .Net MongoDb driver is unable to convert dates to string applying provided format, we can try to apply the opposite approach I used in the previous example to both *the start of the current day* and *the start of next day*, converting the `==` condition to a new condition based on `<` and `>=`:

```
var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
var currentDate = now.Date;
var tomorrow = currentDate.AddDays(1);
var left = currentDate.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
var right = tomorrow.ToUnixTimeSeconds();

var results = await Settings.DataBase.GetCollection<Video>("Videos")
        .Find(x => x.ViewsToday != null && 
              x.ViewsToday.Date >= left && 
              x.ViewsToday.Date < right)
            .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: This is the problem, I need to compare the date, and in Unix there is also time, it is different / For this, I convert it to the string MM/dd/yyyy

Comment: Ok, I got it. .Net MongoDb driver is unable to convert for you date to string applying the format you provide, so... the solution can be obtaining current datetime from system, obtaining the `long` values corresponding to the start of the day and the start of the next day and rewrite the query using `<` and `<=`... i try to edit my answer to use this approach.